# how to solve this error : "Undefined symbols for architecture arm64"

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, swift, xcode

I am getting this error continue, and there is no any error in the particular class. Can anyone tell me that how can i fix this error ?

**Undefined symbols for architecture arm64:**
  "_OBJC_CLASS_$_MYCLASS", referenced from:
      objc-class-ref in MYCLASS.o
ld: symbol(s) not found for architecture arm64
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)

Comment: Please check if MYCLASS.m or MYCLASS.swift is there or not in "Compile Sources" section under "Build Phases" tab.

Comment: Hello Anoop - Thanks for reply. Yes its there available in the xcode in compile sources.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

1. Press "Cmmand+Shift+K" to clean up, and quit Xcode.
2. delete the cache
   Run "rm -rf ~/Library/Developer/Xcode/DerivedData" in terminal
3. open the project and re-build it

Answer (score 2):

You need to add necessary framework to your project. Check all third party party framework and search its required framework for support. For eg if you add google analytic then you need to add CoreData , Foundation etc framework. There is some framework is missing for which third party framework needs.

Comment: Hello ChanWarde - I dont have any third party framework added in my code. But then also i have checked and confirmed that there is not required framework is missing.

Comment: Do you have any my class named file in your project?

Comment: Did you copied that file from any other project?

Comment: Do one thing create new file from add new file in your project and remove your current MyClass from project and build it. if it builds then copy and paste your code in new file .

Answer (score 1):

I think the error says you have not defined a member function of the class.
In my case I forgot to define the constructor function and got this error. It usually depends on the compiler that you are using, for some compliers this error is not seen.